# what is the coversion details of temperature usnig lm35?

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors

I found similar type of code in many sites for coverting analog signal lm35 to centigrade.
But i can't understand that fully. So I need some help what this equation means

```
tempC = (5.0 * tempC * 100.0)/1024.0;
```

Thank you,

Comment: That equation doesn't *quite* make sense. Are you sure you copied it accurately?

Answer (score 3):

I took a quick look at the data sheet for [LM35](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm35.pdf) and it says that each centigrade means a 10 millivolt change.

If you have an ADC with 10-bit resolution, it means you have 1024 steps from 0 V to 5 V.

The temperature is then:

tempC = 5 * (ADCdata / 1024) * 100

This is equal to your equation. So it seems to be correct.

**EDIT:**

A more thorough explanation of the formula:

Lets call the value you read from your LM35 "ADCdata". The range of this value is determined by the resolution of the Analog-to-Digital Converter (ADC). The ADC converts a voltage to a digital value in the Arduino. This value is again what I refer to here as "ADCdata".

If the ADC resolution is 10-bits, it means the 5 volt input can be divided into 1024 equal levels. One level is about 5 millivolts (five thousands of a volt).

To find what value "ADCdata" is in volts we need to divide it with the resolution (1024) and multiply with 5 volts.

Lets say we have a 2.5 volt input signal. The ADCdata will then be 512. If we now divide 512 by 1024 we get 0.5. Lets multiply that with 5 volts and we get 2.5 volts!

We know from the data sheet that 10 millivolts equals 1 centigrade. Since we have our value in volts (2.5 V, which is the same as 2500 millivolts) we need to multiply it with 100 to get centigrades.